Direct procedure for the maximal unitalization of commutative C*-algebra
We know for a commutative nonunital C*-algebra, we can find it maximal unitalization through the stone-cech compactification of its Gelfand spectrum. I wonder if there is a direct construction for this unitalization. For instance, we know that the minimal unitalization of $A$ can be found by the alexandrof compactification of its spectrum $\sigma(A)$, but it also has the direct construction of $A\oplus \mathbb{C}$. Is there an analogous process for the maximal unitalization?

The algebra of continuous functions on $\beta X$, for any locally compact Hausdorff space $X$ (or, more generally, for any completely regular space $X$), is just $C_b(X)$, so one answer would be the maximal unitization of $A$ is $C_b(\sigma(A))$. Another answer (which avoids mentioning $\sigma(A)$ altogether) is that it is the multiplier algebra $M(A)$ of $A$. See Section 2.1 of Murphy's "$C^\ast$-algebras and operator theory" for the definition of multiplier algebras and Example 3.1.3 of the same book for the fact that $M(C_0(X)) = C_b(X)$ for locally compact Hausdorff $X$.
